# Appending a tuple to a np array returns a list of scalars instead of tuples

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, tuples

I'm trying to create a numpy array of tuples, but the resulting np array contains scalars instead of tuples.

I have:

```
log_df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
nod_intervals = np.array([])
for index, row in log_df.iterrows():
    if row['gesture'] == 'Nod' and row['label'] == 'y':
        nod_intervals = np.append(nod_intervals, (row['start'], row['end']))

 print nod_intervals
```

The result is:

```
[  700072.   711071.  1123467.  1133810.  1799492.  1810464.  3861590. 3871927.  4124862.  4135798.  5097266.  5107561.  5392353.  5402949. 5528955.  5539925.  6056021.  6066913.  6730803.  6741807.]
```

As you can see, these are scalars, not tuples.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show us some sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not going to be using the array for anything useful (vectorized operations), just use a list.

```
nod_intervals = []
for index, row in log_df.iterrows():
    if row['gesture'] == 'Nod' and row['label'] == 'y':
        nod_intervals.append((row['start'], row['end']))
```

Possibly faster (not a guarantee):

```
m = log_df['gesture'].eq('Nod') & log_df['label'].eq('y')
nod_intervals = log_df[m][['start', 'end']].apply(tuple, 1).values
```

Comment: for the append , we do not need assign it back right  ?`nod_intervals.append((row['start'], row['end']))` enough right  ?

Comment: I will have a lot of data so I want the speed of numpy

Comment: @dirtysocks45 Trust me, `np.append` is _much slower_ than `list.append`.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize that. Thank you.

Comment: Which user had the second answer?

Comment: @dirtysocks45 I mean my second answer, with apply.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the syntax so I'll just keep it simple with your first answer.

Comment: @dirtysocks45 most of time naive python method is faster than those 'fancy' function

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct behaviour. `Numpy.append` will flatten your data and add it. Have a look at the example here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.append.html

Nested arrays are not really a good idea. Maybe you want a multi-dimensional array. Either way, using `append` as you may a Python list is extremely inefficient, and it is better to assign an empty array and then fill it.

Comment: How do I get a list of tuples then?